# GetThreadSelectorEntry throwing ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED for x64 App

Tags: debugging, winapi

I trying to write a very simple app to debug a Win32 64-bit app. My end goal is to get the TIB and PEB of the remote thread, but for some reason the way I did this on 32-bit app is not working for 64-bit ones (Aside from looking at Esp vs Rsp and checking SegFs vs SegGs). The code I'm trying to use is here:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  LDT_ENTRY             entry;
  DWORD                pid;
  HANDLE               hThread;
  HANDLE               hSnapshot;
  CONTEXT               context;
  context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_CONTROL;

  if(argc < 2){
    printf("Usage: %s PID\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  pid = atoi(argv[1]);

  THREADENTRY32 te32;
  te32.dwSize = sizeof(te32);
  hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD,0);
  while(Thread32Next(hSnapshot, &te32)){
    if(pid == te32.th32OwnerProcessID){
      hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, 0, te32.th32ThreadID);
      if(!hThread)
        exit(1);

      if(SuspendThread(hThread) == (DWORD) -1)
        exit(1);

      if(!GetThreadContext(hThread, &context))
        exit(1);

      printf("Rsp = 0x%x\n", context.Rsp);

      if(!GetThreadSelectorEntry(hThread, context.SegGs, &entry)){
        LPSTR buff = NULL;
        FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, 
          GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&buff, 0, NULL);
        printf("Error: %s\n", buff); //ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED 50 0x32 The request is not supported.
        LocalFree(buff);
        exit(1);
      }
    }
  }
  CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
  return 0;
}
```

but it's always throwing an error at "GetThreadSelectorEntry". The error code that's thrown is ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED: The request is not supported.

I am not able to understand why it's not supported. Does anyone know why?

**[EDIT]**

Okay GetThreadSelectorEntry is not available to x86_64 processes, does anyone know how I can get the TIB/PEB addresses of a remote process?

Comment: *GetThreadSelectorEntry is only functional on x86-based systems. For systems that are not x86-based, the function returns FALSE.*

Comment: Yeah, I did read that. But I've seen people referrer to x86 architecture as being both the 32-bit and 64-bit types, as apposed to say ARM. I wasn't sure if x86_64 was also included in what they called x86-based systems. I really does make sense though. ty.

Comment: this api not implemented on x64. no any ldt here. and you at all not need it

Comment: *how I can get TIB/PEB addresses of a remote process?* - very easy. via `NtQueryInformationProcess`  with `ProcessBasicInformation` and  `NtQueryInformationThread` with `ThreadBasicInformation`

Comment: Okay Thank You! I'm going to read about those right now, I had a feeling I was going about this the wrong way, this is a huge time saver for me. Ty.